# How do I expand the output display to see more columns of a data.table in R using VS code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I am using `visual studio code` to write `R` scripts. Currently, the `data.table` with multiple columns looks like this in the terminal:

```
     Durations   ukey                    Id   event      Side    Qty
 1:   13003012 10000002 1230100000000000001  ABCDE       B        0
 2:   13003014 10000003 1230100000000000002  ABCDE       B        0
 3:   13003014 10000004 1230100000000000003  ABCDE       S        0
 4:   13003018 10000001 1230100000000000004  ABCDE       S        0
 5:   13003023 10000005 1230100000000000005  ABCDE       S        0
        Price        CashFlow       Ts      Qty
 1:        NA              0  93003012       70   
 2:        NA              0  93003012       50   
 3:        NA              0  93003012       30   
 4:        NA              0  93003114       40   
 5:        NA              0  93003114       40
```

Some columns will be displayed below. In python, I can use

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows',50)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',50)
pd.set_option('display.width',100)
```

to adjust the output display. Are there any similar settings in `R`?

Comment: options(width = 100)

Comment: @IRTFM right thanks! It's neat

Comment: I’m not aware of any max columns option for console display. There is a setting for the maximum lines of output. I think its default is 1000. I think that pkg:datatable has its own style of line limitations.

Comment: I suspect there are parameters in the print.data.table function. Use ? For help()